# Why am I receiving multiple values in the method when I'm sending a <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> as args in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-multithreading

I'm implementing a multi threading concept that will divide a bulk `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` into some chunks. When I'm sending it as args to the target function I'm getting the error like

`TypeError: thread_chunking() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.

I tried with receiving as *args in the target method but it is giving as tuple without the content only heading inside of it.

My code is below,

```
thread_chunk=pandas.read_sql("some sql here")
....
thread_name= threading.Thread(target=self.thread_chunking,args=thread_chunk[0:100]))
```

So how can I pass a   to a target function in threading in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`args` is the argument tuple for the target invocation.
Try to maybe pass this as:

```
thread_name= threading.Thread(target=self.thread_chunking,args=(thread_chunk[0:100],))
```

See if it works...

Link to the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects

Comment: @Vanjith Perfect! :D